# Targeting a specific URL in the page and retrieving the value

Tags: jquery, regex, greasemonkey

**Problem**

I have a Greasemonkey script, and it is checking a DIV which has two A HREF contained within it.

I'm trying to target the second A HREF to get at the venue ID string, but I don't know how to target it correctly using RegEx (because RegEx always does my head in).

The second A HREF being targeted goes as follows:

```
<a href="/venue/X">Venue name</a>
```

- With X being the numerical ID for the venue.

**HTML example**

```
<div class="boxContainer">
    <div class="content">
        <h3><img src="https://4sqstatic.s3.amazonaws.com/img/crown-a90b8cffe95be2f88fb5b1c203313a3d.png" height="25" width="25" alt="crown" /><strong><a href="/braskic">Andrew Braskic</a></strong> @ <a href="/venue/4314657">Ascot Car Park</a></h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code so far**

The targeting is being done at *var venueID*, and thanks to my poor RegEx knowledge I don't know how to get at only the second HREF (example below gets the info from the first HREF - refer to the HTML example above to see the first HREF within the DIV):

```
var SearchFriendLinks  = $("div.boxContainer div.content > a");


SearchFriendLinks.each (function () {

    var jThis       = $(this);
    var venueID     = jThis.attr ('href').replace (/\D+(\d+)$/, '$1');
    jThis.parent ().append (' (' + venueID + ') ');
    jThis.parent ().append ('<a href="/venue/' + venueID + '/edit">Manage venue</a>');
    jThis.parent ().append ('&nbsp;|&nbsp;');
    jThis.parent ().append ('<a href="/edit_venue?vid=' + venueID + '">Edit venue</a>');
} );

GM_addStyle ( (<><![CDATA[
    div.FriendResult div.name > a + a
    {
        font-size:      0.7em;
        margin-left:    2em;
    }

]]></>).toString () );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the following `$("div.boxContainer div.content > a");` won't work because div.content's next element is a H3, not a A. The ">" selector is used to select a direct child.

If you're looking to just find any of the A elements that start with "/venue/", you could do this:

```
// Select all links with the word venue in them
$('a[href^="/venue/"]')
```

If the plan is to add links after the venue link, you could do this:

**Update**: I've updated the code below slightly to as per suggestions from @Brock Adams. I've kept the array of match A elements separate as a variable, I've updated the query to be much more specific (rather than just `a[href^="/venue/"]` before) and finally, I've added an if statement to make sure that the `this.href.match()` return a non-null variable. If `match()` fails, it returns `null` and the `if` will not be executed.

```
var SearchFriendLinks = $('div.boxContainer div.content h3 a[href^="/venue/"]');

SearchFriendLinks.each(function()
{
  var venue = this.href.match(/(\d+)$/);

  if ( venue && venue[1] )
    $('<a href="/venue/' + venue[1] + '/edit">Manage venue</a>').insertAfter(this);

  // Do more useful stuff here.
});
```

Comment: This answer will work -- AFAICS -- but it is a step backwards from the OP's starting code.   Some issues: (1) Keep the separate links variable. This helps with debugging and if the OP wants to functionalize the code (DRY paradigm). (2) The overly broad selector *might* be OK for the target site, but most often, it results in false positives and also makes it hard to tune the response for different cases. (3) Notice that the OP's code will fail gracefully.  But using `match()` this way will result in the script hard crashing in the event of a page change or false positive.

Comment: @Brock Adams - Those were some great comments. I've updated my code above. Let me know if anything else catches your eye. :)

Comment: Well, since you followed my suggestions, I have to +1. ;)